# I don't understand a condition in a loop

Tags: java

I am reading some code in Java and I don't understand the condition of this loop:

```
for (Integer label : labelConj) 
{...........
}
```

"label" is an integer and "labelConj", a set of integers. What does the condition control? I can't find any information in Java tutorials. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It will move on all the elements one by one

Answer (score 11):

It's not a condition, it's a foreach loop. It's saying "for each `Integer` (which will be called `label` inside the loop body) in the collection of `Integers` called `labelConj`, loop." The loop will execute once for each item, and then stop.

This syntax can be used with most of the collection classes in the Java framework, and classes you write can use it if you either inherit from one of those classes, or implement the `Iterable` interface.

Answer (score 4):

it is a [foreach loop](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html). It iterates over all elements (Integers in your example) in labelConj.

Answer (score 1):

This is the same as:

```
for (int i=0; i<labelConj.length; i++) {
    Integer label = labelConj[i];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This iterate through the List of integers. This is foreach loop in PHP

Answer (score 0):

this is a fast enumeration equivalent to `for (Integer label in labelConj)`

Answer (score 0):

It's a shorthand way of iterating over a collection of things. Here's a link to some information. Just Google 'enhanced for loop'

http://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with

Answer (score 0):

This is a compact form of the for loop (called Enhanced For statement) which loops for all the elements in an array and assigns each element to a given variable (in this case, "label").
See here for ref:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html